# Changing Values in a Form Causes Lag

Tags: javascript, forms, loops

I want to change the value of a from once a second, but when i use this code:

```js
let btn = document.createElement("button");
function sleep (time) { // number of ms
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}
btn.innerHTML = "Save", btn.onclick = function() {
    var value = 0;
    while (true){
      sleep(1000).then(() => {if (value == 1){
        document.getElementById("input").setAttribute('value', '1');
        value += 1;
      } else if (value == 2){
        document.getElementById("input").setAttribute('value', '2');
        value += 1;
      } else if (value == 3){
        document.getElementById("input").setAttribute('value', '3');
        value += 1;
      } else if (value == 4){
        document.getElementById("input").setAttribute('value', '4');
        value += 1;
      } else if (value == 5){
        document.getElementById("input").setAttribute('value', '5');
        value += 1;
      } else if (value == 6){
        document.getElementById("input").setAttribute('value', '6');
        value += 1;
      } else if (value == 7){
        document.getElementById("input").setAttribute('value', '7');
        value += 1;
      } else if (value == 8){
        document.getElementById("input").setAttribute('value', '8');
        value += 1;
      } else if (value == 9){
        document.getElementById("input").setAttribute('value', '9');
        value += 1;
      } else if (value == 0){
        document.getElementById("input").setAttribute('value', '0');
        value = 0;
      }});
    }
}, document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

The tab completely locks up, and I am forced to reload it.  I have also tried using `document.getElementById("input").value = "value";`, but that causes the same thing to happen.  Does anyone know how to fix this (the form does not have a name)?

Comment: Also look into using a switch statement or you might end up on r/programminghorror

Comment: have you tried a set interval? I think it will run "smoother"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have a classic "busy loop" that locks up the browser in executing Javascript code, without giving the browser a chance to do anything else like update the UI or respond to user actions.

Your `while true` loop, with no `break` statement inside, simply runs forever. Each time it runs, you put a Promise there - the result of `sleep(1000).then(...)`, but the resolution of that Promise never gets a chance to be observed. The `.then` doesn't happen automatically after one second, regardless of what else is happening - it can only happen when the browser event loop schedules it to run, which it can't ever do here because you've got synchronous (blocking) code that never ends, but which must be run first.

If, as it seems, you want the effect to run every second, don't bother with a loop and just use `setInterval` rather than `setTimeout`. You don't even want to use Promises here as Promises can only resolve once while `setInterval` runs its handler continually. So all you need is something like this:

```
btn.onclick = function() {
  var value = 0;
  setInterval(function() {/* what you had in the .then goes here */}, 1000);
};
```

Comment: So I forgot to say, but this is a bookmarklet.  When I run it, it does not work.  No errors are logged in the console. What is wrong?  Only a 0 appears in the input field. [Code](https://test-bench.inyourface3445.repl.co/button.js)

Comment: Looking at the actual code you have, which I hadn't looked at closely before, `value` starts at 0 and, if it's zero, is reset to zero. So of course it never changes. I'm sure you are capable of debugging your own logic and making it do what you need.